# Issues with importing large file in click-house

Tags: docker, clickhouse

The following statement loads only partial data (almost 40% of actual) The error is mentioned below:

```
cat  dr_201604.csv | docker run -i --rm \
  --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server \
  yandex/clickhouse-client \
  clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server \
    --query="INSERT INTO dlr FORMAT CSV"
```

> Code: 117. DB::Exception: Expected end of line
>
> read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

This must be a docker issue because clickhouse website does not mention any limit on how much data can be ingested.
dr_201604.csv is more than 4 GB file. If I select only 10 rows (sample.csv) then it loads without any problem.

```
head dr_201604.csv > sample.csv
```

Is there any limit that only about 800 MB data can be piped?

---

Update:

I tried mounting the volume in the container and still able to load exactly the same number of rows as before:

```
docker run -i --rm \
      --volume /home/ec2-user/:/tmp/  --entrypoint=/bin/sh \
      --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server \
      yandex/clickhouse-client \
       -c "cat /tmp/dr_201604.csv | clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server --query='INSERT INTO dlr FORMAT CSV' "
```